# redirect query string with wildcard after it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using htaccess how can I 301 redirect the following?

`domain.com/index.php?r=apiv2/*` to `app.domain.com/index.php?r=apiv2/*`

Where `*` is a wildcard for anything

This is my attempt so far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} r=apiv2(.*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://app.domain.com/index.php?r=apiv2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} r=apiv2(.*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://app.domain.com/index.php?r=apiv2%1 [L,R=301]
```

With %1 back-reference to the last matched RewriteCond pattern